# Remove TemplateField during page load or before databind

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to remove templatefield from gridview during pageload or before databind to GridView. I have 2 data sources for retrieving data. The data retrieved from one of the data sources do not have the columns ExpireDate and ExpireDays.

So I want to delete the templatefields corresponding to ExpireDate and ExpireDays if the GridView is populated from the data source that do not have those 2 fields.

Setting the visibility to false still will have error of DataRowView doesn't contain property name ExpireDate and ExpireDays.

**Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
 <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="No."/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="Course Enroll" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubMember" HeaderText="ChildMember" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expiry Days">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="expDsL" Text=' <%# Eval("ExpiryDays") %>'>
            </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expiry On">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="expDeL" Text=' <%# Eval("ExpiryDate") %>'>
            </asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Function">
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
           <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/editB.gif" ID="btnEdit" runat="server" ToolTip="Edit" CommandName="Edit"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                  <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/delB.gif" ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete" CommandName="Delete"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(Class.ToLower() != "classAA")
     { 
        // using naveen answer can remove the column.
        var expiryDateF = ((DataControlField)GridView1.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>().Where(fid => fid.HeaderText == "Expiry Days").SingleOrDefault());
        var expiryDaysF = ((DataControlField)GridView1.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>().Where(fid => fid.HeaderText == "Expiry On").SingleOrDefault());

        if (expiryDateF != null)
        {
            GridView1.Columns.Remove(expiryDateF);
        }

        if (expiryDaysF != null)
        {
            GridView1.Columns.Remove(expiryDaysF);
        }
     } 

    if(!this.IsPostBack)
    {
         BindData();
    }
}

protected void SaveMember(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //getting member information and perform checking.

    bool success = dbbb.AddMem(memberdetails);
    if(success == true)
    {
        BindData();
    }
    else
    {
         //prompt fail message.
    }
}

protected void BindData()
{
    DataTable dt = dbbb.RetrieveList(); 
    if(dt != null)
    {
         GridView1.DataSource = dt;
         GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton btnDel = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
        btnDel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this member?')");
    }
}
```

How could I delete the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods to achieve this

Method 1 - Remove by Index

```
if(!table.Columns.Contains("CustomerID1"))
{
    //seven is the column index here. ie, 8th column
    CustomersGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(7);
}
```

Method 2 - Remove using Columns Header Text

```
var expiryDateField= ((DataControlField)CustomersGrid.Columns
        .Cast<DataControlField>()
        .Where(fld => fld.HeaderText == "Expiry Date")
        .SingleOrDefault());
if(expiryDateField != null)
{
    CustomersGrid.Columns.Remove(expiryDateField);
}
```

Please not that

1. `CustomersGrid` is the name of the `asp:GridView` here.
2. `table` is the `DataTable` that acts as the `DataSource` of the `GridView`
3. The code should be called before `DataBind` of the `GridView`

Comment: Method 2 successfully remove the expiry days and expiry on. However, another issue occur after i try to add new member, triggering SaveMember then bind latest data again. During RowDataBound, the imagebutton btnDelete become null value. It has no problem when page load. If i comment the expiry on and expiry days column in .aspx and remove method 2, it has no problem during RowDataBound and btnDelete can be found. Is the method 2 will cause the ImageButton lost in the gridview?

Comment: all the itemTemplate inside GridView1 will be lost instead of only the btnDelete.

Comment: Solved it, need turn ViewState off if a gridview has templatefield. Thanks.

Comment: Setting the ViewState of Gridview to false did help in preserving the itemtemplate and Save method can work well, but the imagebutton can no longer do postback to trigger to deletion or edition in OnRowCommand. Any idea to preserve the templatefield, allowing postback and the imagebutton can still be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the rowDataBound event of the grid, there you can set it dynamically.

You have to know the datasource name of the field you want to hide,
for example the headertext for the cell is "SomeHeader", but the databoundfield name for that cell is

> "SomeOtherName"

then you have to check it like this (debug through GetColumnIndexByName) and
check the value of

> ((BoundField)cell.ContainingField).DataField

```
int GetColumnIndexByName(GridViewRow row, string columnName)
{
    int columnIndex = 0;
    foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.ContainingField is BoundField)
            if (((BoundField)cell.ContainingField).DataField.Equals(columnName))
                break;
        columnIndex++; // keep adding 1 while we don't have the correct name
    }
    return columnIndex;
}

remember that the code above will use a BoundField... then use it like:

protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int index = GetColumnIndexByName(e.Row, "SomeOtherName");
        string columnValue = e.Row.Cells[index].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for didn't explain clearly. There are more templatefield in the gridview instead of only the 2 mentioned, is it possible to retrieve the needed index by header text?

Comment: making the visibility false doesn't help. Still error saying 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ExpiryDays'.

Comment: And also post the data you bind to the grid, I wanna see how does it look like and also how you bind it.